# Response is not defined in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why after launch my function, console throw me:

```
ReferenceError: Response is not defined
```

my code:

```
    @Get('/download/:fileId')
    @Header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    async downloadFile(
        @Param('fileId') id: number,
        @Res() response: Response
    ) {
        const fileName= await this.reportService.getFileName(id);
        response.headers.set('Content-Type',`attachment; filename=${fileName}`);
        
        return await this.fileService.downloadFile(id);
    }
```

my funciton is to download file frmo local folder in project with using NestJS,

thanks for any help

Comment: Well, have you imported `Response` into your file from anywhere?

Comment: `Response` is internal function in TS, i can't import

Comment: What platform is this? This does not look like client-side (DOM) TypeScript to me.

Comment: @nowymailhaha That's `Response<T>` which is the type used by `fetch` which is a client-side function, but your code looks like server-side (NodeJS?) code which has its own `Response` type.

Comment: its Node10 with NestJs and TS

Comment: @Dai, so how can i set header to response?

Comment: Please confirm if this is a runtime error (if so, please post the stack-trace), or a `tsc` compiler error message. Does NestJS compile TypeScript before or after NestJS is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using nest.js and using express, then import `Response` from `express` using `import { Response } from 'express';`

For reference, see the section Library-specific response in [nest.js documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#routing).

Comment: The error message looks like a runtime error, not a TypeScript `tsc` error.